# Java parser for self-made grammar rules

Tags: java

Here are the language rules:

```
myCalculus ::= expr◃▹myCalculus|expr 
expr ::= term+expr|term  
term ::= factor∗term|factor  
factor ::= (myCalculus)|num  
num ::= const  
◃▹ ::= <|>|<=|>=  
where const ∈ (−∞, ∞).
```

I'm creating a parser for class. The user has to enter in the equation with a space between each element. Each element is then read into the same array in it's own index. My method runs into the error java.lang.NumberFormatException. I understand what the error means, but was having a hard time solving it. I know it lies within the "//if next element is an operational element" of the factor class, but am not sure what cases I'm not accounting for.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Interpreter{
    public static void main(String []args){
    //read in the values as a string
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String expressions = scan.nextLine();
    //save each token into the array
    String[] token = expressions.split("\\s+");

    //call the lexer with user input to check for syntax errors
    Lexer problem = new Lexer();
    problem.lexer(token);

    //call myCalculus function which will call the other functions
    System.out.println(factor(token, 0));
    }

    public static int myCalculus(String[] token, int i){
        if(token[i].equals("<")){
            return((expr(token, i-1) <  expr(token, i+1)) ? 1 : 0);
        }
        else if(token[i].equals(">")){
            return((expr(token, i-1) >  expr(token, i+1)) ? 1 : 0);
        }
        else if(token[i].equals(">=")){
            return((expr(token, i-1) >=  expr(token, i+1)) ? 1 : 0);
        }
        else if(token[i].equals("<=")){
            return((expr(token, i-1) <=  expr(token, i+1)) ? 1 : 0);
        }
        else{
            return(expr(token, i));
        }
    }

    public static int expr(String[] token, int j){
        if(token[j].equals("+")){
            return(term(token, j-1) + term(token, j+1));
        }
        else{
            return(term(token, j));
        }
    }

    public static int term(String[] token, int k){
        if(token[k].equals("*")){
            return(factor(token, k-1) * factor(token, k+1));
        }
        else{
            return(factor(token, k));
        }
    }

    public static int factor(String[] token, int l){
        //unlike other cases ( can never be the last element
        if(token[l].equals("(")){
            return(myCalculus(token, ++l));
        }
        //parenthesis and not the last element
        else if(token[l].equals(")") && l < (token.length-1)){
            return(myCalculus(token, ++l));
        }
        //number but not the last element
        else if(token[l].matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+") && l < (token.length-1)){
            //there are three cases in this scenario
            //one, the next element is a ) and the last element
            //two, the next element is a ) and not the last element --
            //three, the next element is an operational element

            //if the next element is a ) and the last element
            if(token[l+1].equals(")") && l+1 == (token.length-1)){
                return(Integer.parseInt(token[l]));
            }
            //if next element is an operational element
            else{
                if(l+2 < (token.length-1)){
                    return(myCalculus(token, l+1));
                }
                else{
                    return(Integer.parseInt(token[l]));
                }
            }
        }
        //number and the last element
        else{
            return(Integer.parseInt(token[l]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An IDE with a debugger is your best friend here.  A turn or two with a well chosen break point will sort this out quickly.

Comment: Have you run this through the debugger? It should be pretty simple to see what the value of token[l] is.

Comment: Your grammar is wrong. It should be `term ::= factor*factor|factor`, and you've left out `primary` altogether.

Comment: With `term ::= factor*factor | factor`, how will you parse something like `1 * 2 * 3`?